# MySQL get date from hour:minute format

Tags: mysql, datetime

For a `where` clause, if I have a `%h:%i` string, how can I get the last existing `datetime` before `now()` with that hour/minute combination?

Some fictional `select` to show the intended behaviour (`comb` is the magical function/combinator I need, which can explicitly depend on `now()` or not):

```
mysql> select now(), comb('20:20');
+---------------------+---------------------+
| now()               | comb('20:20')       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-11-12 20:43:39 | 2016-11-12 20:20:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select now(), comb('20:20');
+---------------------+---------------------+
| now()               | comb('20:20')       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-11-11 01:43:39 | 2016-11-10 20:20:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select now(), comb('20:20');
+---------------------+---------------------+
| now()               | comb('20:20')       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-01-01 01:43:39 | 2015-12-31 20:20:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: You mean last existing in "real life" or in some table with other conditions in the where-clase?

Comment: In "real life". The last phisical datetime moment matching that hour:secs combination.

Comment: @maraca It's for a select statement with other where conditions, but my `comb` is to be used in a `between` statement: `where ... and event_time between comb(hour_min_str) and now()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select concat(date(if(time(now()) > '20:20', now(), date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))), ' 20:20');
```

Comment: Right... I forgot you have to use concat in mysql +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get there (works in any language if the functions are replaced by the corresponding ones):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i') >= '20:20' THEN
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y %d %e'), ' ', '20:20'), '%Y %d %e %H:%i')
  ELSE
    DATE_SUB(
      STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y %d %e'), ' ', '20:20'), '%Y %d %e %H:%i'),
      INTERVAL 1 DAY
    )
  END latest_valid_date
```

Looks like I found a mySQL bug... the else is returning null although it shouldn't... well it works if you subtract the day first... but still this should work.